# AWS AppSync searchItems type return data while table is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I deleted all the items in the `DataTemplate` table but when I query them again with the `searchDataTemplates` endpoint on the app or in AppSync it returns the old data, but when I use the `listDataTemplates` it returns nothing which is correct. Needed to repopulate the data in the table.

data template table

[image: data template table]

search endpoint

[image: search endpoint]

list endpoint

[image: list endpoint]

when I updated items individually it worked just fine but when i deleted all the items from the console (around 700 items) the search endpoint stopped working. Just the search

UPDATE:

I repopulated the data hoping it'd reset but now the `listDataTemplates` shows the new data and the search still shows the old data, is there some cache that needs to be reset?

SECOND UPDATE:

I removed the table and the appsync functions are gone however when i recreated the table (with no data) the testing out the function still returns the old data. I'm guessing the opensearch stuff hasn't been updated?

Answer (score 2):

This issue can only happen if caching is enabled in your application.

I am not sure what's the infrastructure you are using, so i would go ahead with some educated guess. Please feel free to correct me if i overstepped.

From your description of question, you have an AppSync as API layer and DynamoDb as primary database.

If these are the only two resources you have, please check the AppSync cache configuration.

- Open AppSync console
- from left panel select APIs -> your api -> `caching`
- Validate `Caching behavior` is set to `None`

---

In case if you have AWS OpenSearch enabled for search query (i could be wrong, however picking up from previous comment). Then validate the cluster configuration.

- Open AWS Open Search Service console
- From left panel select Domains and click on the openserch domain that you are using
- scroll to the bottom right and look for `Advanced cluster settings` and ensure the attribute `Fielddata cache allocation` is set to **`0`**
- - If `Fielddata cache allocation` is not 0, update the cluster configuration and modify the advanced cluster setting to set the `Fielddata cache allocation` field to `0`.

---

Wait for a few minutes (I would suggest 5 minutes) and then retry your use-case.

---

I hope this would help resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AppSync with `Amplify CLI`, `@searchable` will automatically create the followings:

1. An OpenSearch Domain
2. A Lambda Function that will be attached to the DynamoDB Streams and push the changes (create/update/delete) over to your OpenSearch Domain.

And the problem that you're facing is most likely due to the Lambda Function created failed to push the changes from DynamoDB Streams to OpenSearch. A quick suggestion is to check on the created Lambda Function first.

Reference: [@searchable](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/searchable/)

Comment: Where can I find that created lambda function? Kinda new to this.

Comment: Echoing the above comment. I've gone into my AppSync console and looked in the 'Functions' section. I can't find any functions that deal with pushing changes from DDB to OpenSearch?

Answer (score 0):

I after a while I finally got it work. I ended up creating an item with the same id and deleted it right after. After trying it in AppSync I created a script to create and delete all the ids that were coming back from the searchQuery instead of doing it one by one in AppSync console.